# Ionic 3 File plugin, can't write files on device

Tags: android, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am doing an app using ionic 3 and the file plugin, i am trying to write a json string to a json file under my assets folder which this hierarchy  :
-assets -> mock -> msg-list.json , with assets as the folder from the ionic files.

When using the file plugin :

```
this.file.writeExistingFile("file://android_asset/www/assets/mock/","msg-list.json",JSON.stringify(data))
            .catch(
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              }
          );
```

I always get an error with the code 1000, which is the one for the bad url, i did remove a "/" after file: ( there has been 3 ) and still got the 1000 code error.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the application folder ( file://android_asset ) is read only so you could not write in this folder

read on the readme here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

[image: Android file system layout]

you can use `applicationStorageDirecory` (`this.file.applicaTionStorageDirecory)` which is /data/data/:app-id:, you are able to write there.

So your solution would be

**First step.**

copy the file `msg-list.json` from the application's file `assets/mock` to data storage file, when app is launched (add this in app.component.ts and on platform ready)

```
 this.file.copyFile(this.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/assets/mock', 'msg-list.json', this.file.applicationStorageDirectory, 'msg-list.json').then(...)
```

**Second step.**

you can now read and write the file in the data storage everywhere in your app.
To write the file I suggest to use `writeFile`  function (not `writeExistingFile`) because the `writeExistingFile` function is just `writeFile` with the option: `{replace: true}` ([see source code her](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/file/index.ts)) . And with writeFile function you can set the options you want.

```
export interface IWriteOptions {
  replace?: boolean;
  append?: boolean;
  truncate?: number; // if present, number of bytes to truncate file to before writing
}
```

so for editing the file in data storage, I'd use like below:

```
this.file.writeFile(this.file.applicationStorageDirectory,"msg-list.json",JSON.stringify(data), {append: true}).then(...).catch(...)
```

Finally. always use data storage file.

NB:
use: `this.file.applicationDirectory` instead of using directly `file:///android_asset` and use `this.file.applicationStorageDirectory`

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I don't know how I didn't see the readable only directory.